# IF function and nested function

Tags: excel-formula

Please help with this formula

```
=if(C27>=16000,16M,if(C27,=16999,16M,if(c27>=17000,17M,if(C27<=17999,17M,if(C27>=18000,18M,if(C27<=18999,18M,if(C27>=19000,19M)))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=INT(C27/1000)&"M"
```

You may say I have to fix your formula and spot its obvious syntax error. No, I say you *have to* do it this way, and you always have to look for some neat, simple and deductive alternative before *abandoning* to the ugly, error-prone and difficult-to-maintain nested `IF`s.

And indeed, such alternative exists **most of the time**.

p.s. by the way why is it `M` and not `K`? may be you have a multiplicative unit implicitly in your data, well...

Answer (score 0):

You have a type-o near `16999`.

Try this:

```
=if(C27>=16000,16M,if(C27>=16999,16M,if(c27>=17000,17M,if(C27<=17999,17M,if(C27>=18000,18M,if(C27<=18999,18M,if(C27>=19000,19M)))))))
```

Comment: I really have a problem looking for the right formula to express the following:

Answer (score 0):

```
=if(C27>=16000,16M,if(C27 ,= 16999,16M,if(c27>=17000,17M,if(C27<=17999,17M,if(C27>=18000,18M,if(C27<=18999,18M,if(C27>=19000,19M)))))))
```

the character before 16999 shows the wrong syntax, perhaps it's like this

```
=if(C27>=16000,16M,if(C27<=16999,16M,if(c27>=17000,17M,if(C27<=17999,17M,if(C27>=18000,18M,if(C27<=18999,18M,if(C27>=19000,19M)))))))
```